# Uncaught Error: Unexpected value 'undefined' declared by the module 'AppModule after deleting one module

Tags: angular, module

I just created a module and deleted it due to some reason but after deleting it  I am getting this error in browser console 
`Uncaught Error: Unexpected value 'undefined' declared by the module 'AppModule'
    at syntaxError (compiler.js:2175)
    at compiler.js:20108
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)`

and this error in PowerShell

[image]

app.module

```
    import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
    import { CommonModule }  from '@angular/common';
   import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
    import { AuthService } from './services/auth.service';
    import { CommonService } from './services/common.service';
   import { AuthenticateComponent } from './shared/authenticate/authenticate.component';
    import { LandlordModule } from './landlord/landlord.module';
    import { AuthorizedModule } from './authorized/authorized.module';
    import { HeaderComponent } from './shared/header/header.component';
  import { AuthHeaderComponent } from './shared/auth-header/auth-header.component';

    import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
    import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';
    import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

        import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
    import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

    @NgModule({
      declarations: [
        AppComponent,
        AuthenticateComponent,HeaderComponent,FooterComponent,LeftNavComponent,AuthHeaderComponent,,
      ],
      imports: [
        CommonModule,
        BrowserModule,
        FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule,
        LandlordModule,
        AuthorizedModule,
        AppRoutingModule,
        HttpModule,

      ],
      providers: [{ provide: LocationStrategy, useClass: HashLocationStrategy },AuthService,CommonService],
      bootstrap: [AppComponent]
    })
    export class AppModule { }
```

Please anyone can help me out of this issue

Thanks for your any response.

Comment: Can you share your app module code?

Comment: @Chellappanவ I have updated code

Comment: You Tried To Stop The Server and  then execute ng serve again ??

Comment: Yes, I did it but the same warning in PowerShell

Answer (score 0):

This error can happen if you deleted the module but you didn't remove it from import section of AppModule meta[stackblits](https://stackblitz.com/) for more information

Comment: I created module but I did not imported it app.module file, so I think no need to reomve

Comment: So in that case I can suggest you to remove all the imports then build it and add all the dependency step by step and you will find your mistake.

Answer (score 0):

This is most probably because of that extra `,` that you have here:

```
`AuthHeaderComponent,,`
```

Get rid of this and you probably should get rid of the error.

It should finally look like this:

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { CommonModule }  from '@angular/common';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';
import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { AuthService } from './services/auth.service';
import { CommonService } from './services/common.service';
import { AuthenticateComponent } from './shared/authenticate/authenticate.component';
import { LandlordModule } from './landlord/landlord.module';
import { AuthorizedModule } from './authorized/authorized.module';
import { HeaderComponent } from './shared/header/header.component';
import { AuthHeaderComponent } from './shared/auth-header/auth-header.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    AuthenticateComponent, 
    HeaderComponent, 
    FooterComponent, 
    LeftNavComponent, 
    AuthHeaderComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule, 
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    LandlordModule,
    AuthorizedModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    HttpModule
  ],
  providers: [
    {
      provide: LocationStrategy,
      useClass: HashLocationStrategy
    }, 
    AuthService, 
    CommonService
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

It's really important to have the code readable and properly indented in order to catch these issues right up-front.

Please consider configuring a code formatter like [**Prettier**](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=esbenp.prettier-vscode) on file save.

Comment: I have removed comma as well but not resloved

Comment: Please share your Code as a GitHub repo or a Sample StackBlitz in that case.

Comment: Ok, but can you guess the warning of poweshell